# How to create a newline above text that has a question mark?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I was wondering if anyone could help with this. I'm new to regex so I'm not sure exactly how to do this. I'm using Notepad++. Essentially what I want to do is every time there is an instance where there is a sentence ending with a question mark (?), I would like to create a new line above it.

E.g:

```
Junk text
Junk text
Junk text    
Which of the following statements about the species diversity index is <strong>true</strong>?
```

I would like to appear like:

```
Junk text
Junk text
Junk text   

Which of the following statements about the species diversity index is <strong>true</strong>?
```

Any one have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `^(.*\?)` with `\n\1`.

`^(.*\?)` matches lines with a `?`.

Answer (score 1):

find: `.*[?]$`

replace with : `\n$0`

of course you need check the `Regular expression` button in replace tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

1. Find and replace
2. Check `regular expression` checkbox at `search mode`
3. Search for : `^(.*)\?$`
4. Replace with: `\n\1?`

Example:

```
a
b
c?
d
e?
f
```

Output:

```
a
b

c?
d

e?
f
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex, you should replace

```
(.*)\?$
```

With

```
\r\n\1?
```

Does that do the trick?